# Huawei P30 Android 10, read bitmap stuck

Tags: android

On Android 10(Huawei p30), i am using below code to read bitmap by Uri. But i found sometimes the app will stuck when call decodeStream().

```
Uri imageUri=;//content://media/external/images/media/905472
InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         uri = data.getData();
        InputStream stream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

}
```

to get bitmap from uri use:

```
InputStream stream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
```

This code works for Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 29 and for Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29